# SQL Server - insert into using multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of values in a variable table @vartable

```
id
34
235
34634
3643536
23
234
```

I then want to do the following insert -

```
insert into tableA
values ((select max(tableA_id)+1 from tableA), 2147, (select id from @vartable), 1, 0, 0)
```

So for each id in the @vartable it does an insert using the id on the row.

How do I go about this?

edit to note that I need to update the first value (select max(tableA_id)+1 from tableA) as increasing by 1 each new row it inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into tableA (ColName1,ColName2,ColName3,ColName4,ColName5,ColName6)
Select (select max(tableA_id)+1 from tableA), 2147, id , 1, 0, 0
from @vartable
```

If you need the Max number to be increment, use below query which use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
  Insert into tableA (ColName1,ColName2,ColName3,ColName4,ColName5,ColName6)
  Select (ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY Id)+(select max(tableA_id) from tableA) )as aRow,
          2147, id , 1, 0, 0
  From @vartable

Here is fiddle link -- > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb04f/1
```

Comment: close.  unfortunately what this does is assign all values the same first number (select max(tableA_id)+1 from tableA).  I need this number to increase by 1 each new row it inserts.